# Wordpress multiple pages on one post

Tags: wordpress, single-page-application, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a question about this solution:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Page-Links

Is it working on SPA ? (single page application)

I mean, every page is loading from scratch ? or just the content ?

Thank you very much for helping

Comment: The whole page will be queried. You can refer to [Template Hierarchy Visual Overview](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png) for a better understanding. SPAs and WordPress themes are a whole world apart. To improve performance you could implement a [prerender](https://caniuse.com/link-rel-prerender)/[prefetch](https://caniuse.com/link-rel-dns-prefetch) strategy.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and sorry for my misunderstanding , but when you say the whole page will be queried you mean that the whole page will re loaded every time ?

Comment: Yes, indeed, because you're requesting (query) a new page. You're asking the server to deliver a new information.